# MDADM RAID-1 removes two drives, showing no files on third

Tags: raid, raid-1, mdadm

For a few weeks ago I noticed one of two drives had been removed from my MDADM RAID-1 array on Ubuntu 20.04. I then bought a third disk (in case something was really wrong). It was also a WD RED 1TB, just like the old ones.

I added it, and re-added the old disk as well, and all was good - now using three disks.
However, recently I've noticed another behaviour - both old disks are being removed:

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Jan 24 09:55:37 2018
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 976631488 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976631488 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Jun 24 12:44:43 2021
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       3       8       48        2      active sync
```

The array is mounted as `/storage`, with a lot of content. Here's what I see when the two disks are removed as above:

```
liwa@BRITNEYSPEARS:~$ cd /storage
liwa@BRITNEYSPEARS:/storage$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 24  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Jun  9 23:43 ..
```

(Yeah, I know, I have a super-cool hostname!)

So, using a degraded array I cannot access ANY data. When I had the two disks, data was still accessible during the degradation (I think?).

But back to the present:
`shutdown -r now` followed by `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` gives me:

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Jan 24 09:55:37 2018
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 976631488 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 976631488 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Thu Jun 24 14:14:20 2021
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 3
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : Atlas:0
              UUID : f2da90a1:ab543094:7b6d30ff:aa03dafd
            Events : 28498

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       2       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       3       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
```

So, the array is back, and so is `ls -la /storage`.

What can I learn from this? Are sdb and sdc passed due date? And why aren't the files being listed using a degraded array with just sdd?

All disks (including the OS disk, sda) get a **PASSED**, using `smartctl -a`.

Comment: What is strange, in your first `--detail` I see no system device name in the last column below (like `/dev/sdX`) after `active sync`, while in your last `--detail` everything is in place. Back up your data and check array consistency by issuing: `echo check > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action`. Also, were there any interesting messages in `dmesg`?

Comment: I noticed that too! I checked dmesg, but when I did, I couldn't really find anything. It was a few hours ago when I first checked dmesg. Maybe I could grep on something?

Found this though (might also be unrelated):
[    4.846784] kfd kfd: error getting iommu info. is the iommu enabled?
[    4.846805] kfd kfd: Error initializing iommuv2 for device 1002:9874
[    4.846846] Creating topology SYSFS entries
[    4.848554] kfd kfd: device 1002:9874 NOT added due to errors

Comment: dmesg that could be helpful is the one before reboot. The reboot cleared or smudged the error state of the system, so only traces that might be left are all on the non-volatile storage, that's why I suggest checking the array. Also, probably it's worth to run memtest. I had never seen MD RAID to misbehave by itself; there always was some serous hardware problem.

Comment: Ah okay! I'll remember that and will check dmesg as soon as I notice it next time. Is a backup necessary before the check? I mean, it's always necessary, but the check itself doesn't mess anything up?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest doing a backup, and more, don't remove any previous valid (tested) backup if you have one, because this new one might be faulty. The condition is very strange, I bet nobody will predict what's going on and what'll be with the data if you just check consistency. We don't know what's on disks.

Comment: Having said that, I'd suggest you to decode component superblock contents with `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb` and so on. You don't have to disarm device from the RAID for that. That might shine some light.

Comment: It's just a file storage - I'll make some copies to another server and try it out. This is a mission for the weekend! Thanks a lot so far - I'll get back with the results :)